# How to rewrite a query without using subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

First, some background on what I'm trying to do:
I have a table called Invoices and if I run this two SELECT I get the following:

```
SELECT AID, PPID, Amount, Type, Invoice FROM Invoices WHERE Type > 3 AND PPID = 2250
```

| AID | PPID | Amount | Type | Invoice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 443 | 2250 | 4500 | 5 | 0 |

```
SELECT AID, PPID, Amount, Type, Invoice FROM Invoices WHERE Type > 3 AND PPID = 1442
```

| AID | PPID | Amount | Type | Invoice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 77 | 1442 | 4500 | 5 | 0 |
| 225 | 1442 | 4500 | 5 | 0 |

So when PPID = 2250 it returns only 1 row and when PPID = 1442 it returns 2 rows(and that's fine)

Now I have a query here that only brings me the records that returns only one row (PPID = 2250) and if it returns more than one row(PPID = 1442) it won't bring anything.

```
SELECT
(SELECT TOP 1 I2.AID FROM cgpaccounts.dbo.Invoices I2 WHERE I2.Invoice = I1.Invoice AND I2.Type > 3 AND I2.PPID = I1.PPID) AS PaymentID,
I1.AID AS ChargeID,
CAST(I1.Amount AS FLOAT)/100 AS Amount,
I1.Invoice
FROM Invoices I1
WHERE I1.type <> 2 AND I1.type < 4 AND I1.Amount > 0 AND I1.PPID = 1442--added for tests only 
AND (SELECT COUNT(I3.AID) FROM Invoices I3 WHERE I3.Invoice = I1.Invoice AND I3.Type > 3 AND I3.PPID = I1.PPID) = 1
```

So I want to rewrite that query not using subqueries (I'm running it in a AccessDB and it's taking a huge amount of time, I rewrote other queries and by removing the subqueries it improved, but I'm stuck on this one now).

I've got this far already, but to be honest, I'm not sure if I'm on the right way of thinking here.

```
SELECT
I2.AID AS PaymentID,
I1.AID AS ChangeID,
I1.Amount / 100 AS Amount,
I1.Invoice
FROM Invoices I1
INNER JOIN Invoices I2
ON I2.PPID = I1.PPID AND I2.Invoice = I1.Invoice
WHERE I2.Type > 3 AND I1.type <> 2 AND I1.type < 4 AND I1.Amount > 0 AND I1.PPID = 1442--added for tests only
```

When I run it with PPID = 2250 I get the following result: (this is what I expect)

| PaymentID | ChargeID | Amount | Invoice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 443 | 83 | 45 | 0 |

When I run it with PPID = 1442 I get the following result: (not what I'm expecting, I think there's something wrong in my logic there, and I'm getting duplicated results)

| PaymentID | ChargeID | Amount | Invoice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 77 | 76 | 45 | 0 |
| 225 | 76 | 45 | 0 |
| 77 | 224 | 45 | 0 |
| 225 | 224 | 45 | 0 |

In summary, what I'm trying to do is to rewrite that query without the subqueries and also add the condition to bring only the results where only 1 row is returned.

I know this is quite a long question, but I tried to give as much information as possible.

I hope someone can help me, or guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read (and write.) Properly formatting makes SQL much easier.

Comment: @jarlh Thanks for letting me know, and I'd be happy if you could show me a proper way of formatting it

Comment: E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70100735/apply-groupby-function-in-sql has much easier to read SQL.

Comment: @jarlh thank you, I've edited it, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0):

Try the script below adding the DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
I2.AID AS PaymentID,
I1.AID AS ChangeID,
I1.Amount / 100 AS Amount,
I1.Invoice
FROM Invoices I1, Invoices I2
WHERE I2.PPID = I1.PPID 
  AND I2.Invoice = I1.Invoice
  AND I2.Type > 3
  AND I1.type <> 2
  AND I1.type < 4 
  AND I1.Amount > 0 
  AND I1.PPID = 1442
```

Comment: It didn't work, but thank you, the results are still the same I was getting previously